# Can we use ReactJS to animate elements according to how much the user scrolls

Tags: reactjs, scroll, frontend

Specifically, can we use React to replicate [Apple's Airpod Pro website](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/)?
And how about the performance?

Comment: Better to search in google, try something and ask a question if you encounter a problem

Answer (score 1):

React is a framework that allows you to create and control your html using js. It doesn't have any solution for animation on scroll event out of the box. Though it is usually easy to add any kind of library and use it with react.

[Check that list of libraries to do animation during scrolling](http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/6-javascript-scroll-libraries-to-use-in-2017/)

Most likely your choice will be [ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io/)

About performance: add events on scroll is always bad for performance. But it will be 100% dependent on **what animation** you are going to implement and **how you are going to implement it**. Especially it will affect scrolling performance on mobile. Though there is a solution that might (or might not) help you solve bad mobile performance. [Check google post about passive events.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners)